# What's the best way to present an e-mail address on my website without being attacked by spammers?

Tags: html, webforms, spam-prevention

What's the best way to present an e-mail address on my website without being attacked by spammers?

The approach `foo at fooland dot com` is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to present it in a way that is comprehensible for normal people.

**EDIT**

The displaying e-mails are dynamic

Comment: @Ciwee: What server technology are you using?

Comment: @richard ev: ASP.NET and jQuery

Comment: @Ciwee: MVC or WebForms?

Comment: What kind of "normal people" are you dealing with? Everyone I've ever met can read words like "at" and "dot".

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work

Comment: This will also soon be blogged about on the [superuser blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com) due to the popularity of the Super User question.

Comment: any way to protect this question from spammers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does e-mail obfuscation really make automatic harvesting harder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259363/does-e-mail-obfuscation-really-make-automatic-harvesting-harder)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a [recent answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work/235965#235965) which addresses this exact question by comparing a whole range of commonly used methods.

Answer (score 8):

I've used:

- reCAPTCHA Mailhide http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/gracefulemailobfuscation/

Answer (score 7):

How a about using a simple image that features your email address?

A technique to dynamically generate the image could be to add an ASP.NET MVC controller to your WebForms project with an action method that returns a `FileResult` containing a dynamically-generated image containing the email address.

```
public class DynamicImageController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public FileResult Email(int id)
    {
        // TODO: Code that uses the ID value to retrieve the
        // email address for this customer (for example)
    }
}
```

On your web form you could use an image server control, and set the `ImageUrl` accordingly (something like `"/DynamicImage/Email/" + customerId`) from the code behind.

This page has an example illustrating how to use a `FileResult` to render an image (a chart in this scenario)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MvcChartControlFileResult.aspx

Comment: That's a solution, but I would have to generate the image dynamically because the presented e-mails are dynamic. If I was to generate, then I would prefer a javascript approach.

Comment: +1 Simple and effective.

Comment: Has the disadvantage of being a hassle for whomever needs to use the address, though.

Comment: Yeah, can't click on it, can't copy it.. as a user, that would be well past my maximum effort-required threshold, unless I was *really* intent on emailing you.

Answer (score 4):

One that I've started using is CSS code redirection:

```
<span style="unicode-bidi:bidi-override; direction: rtl;">moc.niamodruoy@uoy</span>
```

You could use some type of String.Reverse feature (depending on the language you use) to insert the dynamic e-mail addresses on the page.

This is one of the easiest and effective ways.  Check out some others here: https://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work

Answer (score 2):

The downside with the image-based approach is that it cant be copy-pasted by users.

I think some kind of JavaScript that renders the email would be nice. If it's tricky enough, bots might not be able (or willing) to find it. For example, say that you start with an image (works for everybody). Then, if the user clicks it, it turns into a copy-pasteable text by some JavaScript-magic.

Another idea would be to replace the image with a text 2 seconds after the page has loaded. If bots are in a hurry (are they usually?) they will only see the image. Also, if the user is quick and tried to select the image before it's replaced, the JavaScript can fire right away and replace it with the proper text. Use a mouseover- or click-event or something like that.

Comment: Javascript is the solution that I'm tending for. I'm willing to render the e-mail as foo-at-fooland-dot-com and place a javascript block right bellow it in the markup that converts it to foo@fooland.com. It's copy-and-pastable and looks good.

Comment: @Ciwee: although my solution differs from yours, I think it's a great idea to display the name-at-domain-dot-com thing and dynamically change it to a normal (clickable) mailto link using JavaScript. Thanks for the inspiration, I'll definitely write a script like that for my own sites :)

Answer (score 2):

How about Javascript encoding? A PHP function like this could be used:

```
function encodeEmail ($email) {
  $ret = '';
  $a = '<a href="mailto:' . $email . '">' . $email . '</a>';
  $i = 0;
  $c = substr($a, $i, 1);
  while ($c != FALSE) {
    $ret .= '%'.dechex(ord($c));
    $c = substr ($a, ++$i, 1); 
  }
  return "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(unescape('$ret'));</script>";
}
```

(the code might need some correcting, as I wrote it without checking for errors).

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.org">email@example.org</a>
```

Seriously, in my opinion, none of these solutions is worth the extra hassle to your users.

Spam filters are really good these days (I get almost no spam in my gmail, and I always use my email address straight up) and if you want to reach an audience, your priority should be their comfort, not yours.

Maybe this is a subjective question though :)

Comment: I agree. My email address have been posted on my webpage, in the contact data of my domains, and in many sites for at least 5 years and there isn't a single day that I have to mark more than 2 or 3 spam messages. My income depends on those contacts, so I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say an image approach if you don't mind about users not being able to copy it.

You can use JavaScript to build the address from some random algorithm you like. You may also put it in an `alert()` which is still copy-able but your email address never touches the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to go like google groups , they don't show u the actual email ID , just the beginning , but then , if u are a human , you can use the captcha approach to verify the visitor as a human or a bot .
Also , you can have a sound file embedded in your system or a flash based display , which shows your email ID . You can create some actionscript flash , it looks good  , attractive and delivers the purpose as well . 
Either sound or a flash , is what I think looks good . You can even create a dynamic image which keeps on changing every time a user reloads the page .
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Someone else mentioned using an image, here's an article on MakeUseOf that links to a site that will build those types of images for you...

http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/hidetext-easily-convert-text-email-addresses-images/